# ASP.NET Core ClaimsTransformation Windows Identity

Tags: asp.net, authentication, identity

I have an ASP.NET Core web app with Windows Authentication. I need some additional info behind the user and I thought using ClaimsTransformation would be a good idea. The idea works in other ways, but I don't seem to have access to the Windows Identity from the ClaimsTransformer. I need the Windows Identity name to resolve the additional info so any ideas how to achieve this?

When I look at the User object from the controller code, it has the Windows Identity (plus ClaimsIdentity), but in the ClaimsTransformer, I only have the ClaimsIdentity available.

Please also suggest better ways to add additional info for the user in some other way, if you think I'm looking at this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I can get the current Windows Identity by calling

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

Now I only have other issues to resolve, but they are another story...

Comment: Though WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() returns the current "RunAs" user which in the case of IIS hosting, is the IIS Application Pool user.

I found out that in Core RC2, I have access to the current HttpContext during ClaimsTransformation and it would solve my problem, but is this doable in RC1?